# JQuery Mobile Multi Page - Custom Back Button Icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, back-button

I've got a `MultiPage` made with JQuery Mobile, but as a last step to finish it, I want to customize my back button from the standard one to a custom .png and produce a page that looks like this:

```
   <div data-role="page" id="2" data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="header" style="background-image:url(background_sun1.png)">
    <div class="ui-grid-a"><img src="teainc_empty.png" width="150"><img src="120.png"><img src="logo.png" width="45"></div>
    <div class="ui-grid-b"><img src="1.png" width="1"></div>
  </div>

    <div data-role="content"style="background-image:url(background_dark.png)">
      <img src = "news_head.png">
        <div><ul style="font-size:14px" id="output1"></ul></div>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" style="background-image:url(background_sun2.png)">
    <div class="ui-grid-b"><img src="1.png" width="5"></div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page 2 -->
```

Is there something I can add to

```
<div data-role="page" id="2" data-theme="a">
```

so that it uses a custom back button and not the default one that is shown?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of using a custom icon in header back button(same for any button)

http://jsfiddle.net/mKfBM/1/

Define a style of the format `.ui-icon-<Replace the brackets with any name you want to choose>`.
Then for the button define `data-role="<Replace the brackets with the name you have chosen>"`
In the example I used `custom-back-icon`.Hence I defined the style like this - `.ui-icon-custom-back-icon`

P.S:This example is not perfect.It is just a sample of how to use a custom icon.Preferably for the icon use dimensions 18x18(which is the dimensions of icons used in jqm framework).In that case you dont have to override the width and height styles.